# sympy assumptions in nsolve not holding

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am trying to solve 2 simultaneous equations, which lead to two sets of x-y values. I only want the x-y set that has a positive x.

I set my assumption in x when defining it to be positive= True. Yet when I get my x-y solutions, I still only get the `[-1.41421356237310], [2.00000000000000]` set when I want `[1.41421356237310], [2.00000000000000]` set. It appears that my assumption to make x positive is not working, although the `print((x).is_positive()` returns True. Why is my assumption not working, and how do I force `nsolve` to assume that x must be positive? The code can be found below.

```py
import sympy as sym

x = sym.symbols('x', positive= True)
y= sym.symbols('y', positive= True)
eq1= sym.Eq(y,x**2)
eq2= sym.Eq(y,2)
result= sym.nsolve((eq1, eq2), (x,y),(-1,-5))
print(result)
print((x).is_positive)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `solve` instead of `nsolve`, because only the former will use the assumptions on the variables:

```
...
result = sym.solve((eq1, eq2), (x, y))
print(result)
```

gives as expected:

```
[(sqrt(2), 2)]
```

(while you get `[(-sqrt(2), 2), (sqrt(2), 2)]` if you remove the `positive=True` assumption on `x`)